# Recursively listing all files in Python, not able to fetch all

Tags: python, recursion

I would like to list recursively all the files starting from my current directory.
My directory structure:

```
│   cat.py
│   cat2.py
│   du.py
│   README.md.txt
│
└───FirstInnerDirectory
    │   file.txt
    │
    └───SecondInnerDirectory
            file2.txt
```

My script:

```
import os

def list_content_recursively(start_point):
    print("Call from: " + start_point)
    for entry in os.listdir(start_point):

        if os.path.isfile(entry):
            print("File: " + entry)

        elif os.path.isdir(entry):
            list_content_recursively(entry)

list_content_recursively(os.getcwd())
```

My output:

```
Call from: C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Programming\week02\03.Files
File: cat.py
File: cat2.py
File: du.py
Call from: FirstInnerDirectory
File: README.md.txt
```

I do not know why it's not returning the file in FirstInnerDirectory and it does not recognize the SecondInnerDirectory as a dir obj. I also tried to change the entry to include the absolute path, but it still failed.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `os.walk()`?

Comment: Reinvent is not the exact word, I just wanna implement a part of it for better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with your current code and modifying as little as possible:

```
import os


def list_content_recursively(start_point):
    print("Call from: " + start_point)

    for entry in os.listdir(start_point):

        full_path = os.path.join(start_point, entry)

        if os.path.isfile(full_path):
            print("File: " + entry)

        elif os.path.isdir(full_path):
            list_content_recursively(full_path)


list_content_recursively(os.getcwd())
```

As you can see, you need the full path when tracking your files down the file path.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
elif os.path.isdir(entry):
    list_content_recursively(entry)
```

`entry` is only the directory name, not it’s full path. You will need to also include `start_point` when you recursively call your function.

```
elif os.path.isdir(entry):
    list_content_recursively(os.path.join(start_point, entry))
```

The same goes for:

```
if os.path.isfile(entry):
    ...
elif os.path.isdir(entry):
    ...
```

The `entry` should also be the full path, you should use `os.path.join(start_point, entry)` to replace `entry`.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of yours, using `pathlib`, and passing absolute paths to `isfile` and `isdir`.

```
import os
import pathlib

def list_content_recursively(start_point):
    print("Call from: " + str(start_point))

    for entry in os.listdir(start_point):

        entry_path = pathlib.Path(start_point) / entry

        if os.path.isfile(entry_path):
            print("File: " + str(entry))

        if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
            list_content_recursively(entry_path)

list_content_recursively(pathlib.Path('.'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say the problem is that you are not *entering* the sub directories. What you really might want is `os.walk` that recursively, for the given directory and sub directories, returns a tuple of :

- current directory
- directories in current directory
- files in current directory

Hence :

```python
def list_content(cwd, directories, files):
     print("Call from: " + cwd)
     for directory in directories:
        print("Directory:" + directory)
     for file in files:
        print("File: " + file)
     print()

for subdir in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
     list_content(*subdir)
```

**Edit:**
I saw after posting that you wanted to reimplement walk so as some help here is another way to do it :

```python
import os

def list_content_recursively():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print("Call from: " + cwd)
    for entry in os.listdir(cwd):

        if os.path.isfile(entry):
            print("File: " + entry)

        elif os.path.isdir(entry):
            os.chdir(entry)
            list_content_recursively()
            os.chdir("..")
```

If you want to start from an arbitrary place you can also wrap it in a function that does a `os.chdir` before, else abccd's answer still stand :)